# Finding the slope in a polar equation

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I was given the following problem:

> For which of the following points on the circle $r=\cos\theta$ is the slope equal to $2$? $\\
> a. \displaystyle \theta=\frac{1}{2} \arctan \Big(-\frac{1}{2} \Big)\\
> b. \displaystyle \theta=\frac{1}{2} \arctan (2)\\
> c. \displaystyle \theta=\frac{1}{2} \arctan \Big(\frac{1}{2} \Big)$

The way I attempted the problem was by converting the polar equation to a parametric (cartesian) equation and using the formula $\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{dy}{dx}$ - and setting that equal to two. This did not seem to get me the right answer.
I looked in the answer key, and the first step given was to:

> Set the equation for the slope equal to 2 and solve for $\theta$.
>   $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{f(\theta)\cos(\theta)+f'(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{-f(\theta)\sin(\theta)+f'(\theta)\cos(\theta)}=2$$

I understand why they are setting the slope equation equal to two, but how did they get this equation as the slope equation?

Comment: What is $f(\theta)$ here?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $\cos(\theta)$ as defined by $r=\cos(\theta)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=f(\theta) \sin\theta$ and $x=f(\theta) \cos\theta$ and so (by product rule)
$$\frac{d y}{d \theta} = f(\theta) \cos \theta + f'(\theta)\sin \theta$$
and
$$\frac{d x}{d \theta} = -f(\theta) \sin \theta + f'(\theta)\cos \theta$$
You said you understand that $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{d y}{d \theta}}{\frac{d x}{d \theta}}$ so I'll let you do that.

Answer (score 0):

$r\cos\theta = x\\
r\sin\theta = y$

$\frac {dx}{dt} = \frac {dr}{dt}\cos \theta - r\sin \theta\\
\frac {dy}{dt} = \frac {dr}{dt}\sin \theta + r\cos \theta$

But instead you might do this.

$x = \cos^2\theta = \frac 12 (\cos 2\theta + 1)\\
y = \sin\theta\cos\theta = \frac 12 \sin 2\theta$

and find $\frac {\frac {dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}$

Or make a picture:

[image]
$r=\cos \theta$ describes a circle with the origin on the circle.

I have added the two lines that are tangent to the circle with slope equal to 2.

$\phi$ would be the angle from the center to the point of tangency.

and $\theta = \frac {\phi}{2}$